# Fatal Error: image.effects.inc for Drupal 7.12 Modules/image/ Directory

Tags: media

I'm getting a message that says:

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare image_effect_info() (previously declared in sites/all/modules/image.effects.inc:14) in /modules image.effects.inc on line 62**

This messes up my whole theme and my [homepage](http://myriadangel.com) when I visit it I'll get the
previously mentioned error.

*When I remove the file image.effects.inc and replace it with new it temporarily 
fixes the problem. I have figured out what is causing the error.* When I go 
to the image module and try to edit scale, effect and update it posts the same
error above.

http://www.myriadangel.com/ -----/******/media/image-styles/edit/thumbnail/effects/1

Is there a patch for this error in image.effects.inc ? Or what would be causing
this to happen. This is part of Drupal 7's core files located at:

drupal.7.12/modules/image**/image.effects.inc**

Error occurs when editing a thumbnail under image styles within the modules.
And randomly my theme will crash with the above fatal error at the end of the 
page.

Thanks a lot!
Troy